# How to check a URL with valid HTTPS certificate in monit?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, monit

I have the following configuration -

```
check host qbox_logstash_1
  with address blah.mysite.com
  group qbox
  if failed
    host blah.mysite.com
    port 443
    type TCPSSL
    protocol https
    http headers [ Authorization: Basic dXJiYW5sYWiYW5sBlaHToHideThisAuthMjM= ]
  then alert
```

It just connects and never checks that the domain has wrong certificate. Why is monit not checking the certificate?

Comment: maybe the 3. point in this source may help you https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/EnableSSLInMonit

Answer (score 6):

You need to include the `certificate valid` directive:

```
if failed
  ...
  certificate valid > 10 days
then alert
```

See the documentation here: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#CONNECTION-TESTING